# How do I say in Japanese "I'm doing much better/healing well"?

Tags: phrases

How would I reply in Japanese to the question how I'm doing (I had surgery last month)? よく治っています is the best I've been able to come up with, but is there some phrase for this or something?

Answer (score 7):

> 「よく治{なお}っています。」

will be understood by basically all native speakers, but it is not what many of us would say ourselves because it sounds a little awkward.  Instead, we would say:

・「よくなっています。」 by using 「なる」

・「よくなってきています。」

・「日{ひ}に日に元気{げんき}になっています。」

etc.

More formally, we might say:

・「快方{かいほう}に向{む}かっています。」